# Equivalent to cvAvg in the OpenCV C++ interface

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm having the same problem issued in these two links: [one](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/How-to-calculate-the-average-pixel-intensity-of-a-small-patch-of-an-IplImage-td5216769.html), [two](http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/71908). I need to calculate pixel intensity average on a small ROI in an image.

I selected the ROI and copied the image in it, so now I need to calculate pixel average intensity, avoiding a loop on all of the pixels.

The answers provided in the links suggest to use `CvScalar c = cvAvg(img);` but I can't find the equivalent, using the C++ interface.

Can you please point it out to me? I couldn't find it in the documentation!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I provide the code snippet solving the problem:

```
//defines roi
cv::Rect roi( roiVertexXCoordinate, roiVertexYCoordinate, roiWidth, roiHeight );

//copies input image in roi
cv::Mat image_roi = inputImage( roi );

//computes mean over roi
cv::Scalar avgPixelIntensity = cv::mean( image_roi );

//prints out only .val[0] since image was grayscale
cout << "Pixel intensity over ROI = " << avgPixelIntensity.val[0] << endl;
```

Comment: I am sorry, i don't know C++. If it works for you, then it means it works. I use only Python, and you can find all contour features including mean here : http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/04/contour-features.html

Answer (score 8):

Use `mean function` for C++.

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=avg#mean

```
Calculates an average (mean) of array elements.

C++: Scalar mean(InputArray src, InputArray mask=noArray())

Python: cv2.mean(src[, mask]) → retval 

C: CvScalar cvAvg(const CvArr* arr,const CvArr* mask=NULL ) 

Python: cv.Avg(arr, mask=None) → scalar
```

Comment: Ok, and the scalar it'll return is the pixel intensity average over the image in input?

Comment: compute mean for each channel separately. And you can use mask for finding mean at ROI.

Comment: ok I c... I forgot to mention that image is grayscale, so in that case it'll return the intensity only over that channel. btw documentation in [opencv 2.1](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#cv-mean) is different, how come?

Comment: avg of grayscale values in ROI. Also, `When all the mask elements are 0’s, the functions return Scalar::all(0) .`

Comment: can you please tell me if the snippet is correct?it seems working fine to me..thks ;D