# Auto Adjust Image Intensity

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have two images to be compared, a test image and a reference image, both are in GREYSCALE. I would like to adjust the intensity of test image to be the same as reference image. (Test image is captured by fixed camera where it's intensity might slightly affected by surrounding environment). I've gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959987/equivalent-to-cvavg-in-the-opencv-c-interface) for reading the image intensity. My problem now is I don't know how to adjust the image intensity.

Example:

Reference image: 89.1413

Test image: 121.416

How should I change the test image intensity value to the same with reference image?

Answer (score 0):

```
Mat correctedImage = testImage * (89.1413/121.416);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by image intensity you mean the average (or mean) value of all image pixels.
In this case you need to add or subtract some constant to all pixels to move the average to the desired intensity.

If you ref. mean is `m0`, and your image intensity is `m1`, then you need to do the following correction:

```
cv::Mat correctedImage = testImage + (m0 - m1);
```

Note that the mean intensity, or *brightness*, is affected by an *additive* factor, and the *contrast* is affected by a *multiplicative* factor (as in the answer by @MichaelBurdinov).

Comment: I think that intensity is also a multiplicative factor, because it depends on reflective properties of objects. When you turn lights ON in a dark room, intensity of bright objects is increased more than intensity of dark objects.

Comment: @MichaelBurdinov: That is why I explicitly stated what *I* mean and not used the original ambiguous terminology. Given that the question asks about a *single* parameter, then IMO a brightness change is the simplest.

Comment: I mean that both brightness and contrast are multiplicative

Comment: @MichaelBurdinov: A multiplicative factor changes *both* the brightness and the contrast, yes. An additive factor changes only the brightness.

Comment: Yes, multiplicative and additive models can be used in proper situations. I am just pointing out that in his situation he probably needs multiplicative approach in order to get images that are as similar as possible (he want to compare images that differ because illumination had changed).